# Can I have a table with two foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am creating a social media site. Users can create a category (1 user to many categories) and each category has many entries. I want to allow users to post on events (1 event can have many posts).

In other words the event owns the post but I want to be able to identify the user who created that post.

Does this mean that I should create 1 event to many posts as well as 1 user to many posts? Does this create normalization problems. What's the best way around this?

Comment: Just to be clear can users post on all categories or just ones they created? And what is a category "entry"?

Comment: Having 2 foreign keys on Posts (events and users) would be the best way to achieve what you want. It would be normalised this way.

Comment: A FOREIGN KEY declaration just tells the DBMS that the values in the columns in the table listed as referencing must appear as values in the columns in the table listed as referenced. Whenever that's the case, declare it. Some DBMSs will not allow cycles in references. (Those DBMSs use the references for other things and the limitation is just their choice.) Such cases are sometimes a mark of poor design. (A DBMS uses constraints to keep out invalid update attempts and to optimize query evaluation. But constraints aren't needed to update or query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any relation between category and events 
In that case add a categoryID as FK in Events

- Users table

  1. userID `Primary key`
- Categories table

  1. categoryID `Primary key`
  2. userID `Foreign Key (users)`
- Events

  1. eventID `Primary key`
- Posts

  1. postID `Primary key`
  2. eventID `Foreign Key (events)`
  3. userID `Foreign Key (users)`